# How do I calculate a series for percentage change since the left-most visible bar?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to code [horizon graphs](https://flowingdata.com/charttype/horizon-graph/) in Pine Script.  However to do this usefully, I need a data series representing percentage change from the value of the first (i.e. left-most) visible bar on the screen.

I know that the normal way of plotting percentage change is simply to configure the y axis to be percentage rather than price - then the left-most visible bar is always shown as 0.00%.  But that doesn't help in a script where I need to do further calculations based on the percentage change since the left-most bar.

I know that I can [reference historical data](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-referencing-operator) by indexing the series for the source data, and initially I thought I could get the price of the left-most bar via that.  But it turns out that this operator works backwards from the right-most bar, in order to use it I would first need to know how many bars to count back to get me from the right-hand edge of the chart to the left-hand edge.

I also know that [`bar_index` gives the index of the current bar](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_bar_index), that [`max_bars_back`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_max_bars_back) can set the history buffer length, and that a [`var` declaration will initialize a variable only once](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#variable-declaration) which is useful for calculating and storing values relating to the first bar in the history.  However these and all the other history-related primitives I've looked at all seem to operate on the history *buffer*, which is often different to the portion of history *displayed* on the *visible* chart.  And I can't find any function or variable which gives me any data about the left-hand side of the x-axis, e.g. its bar index or time.

All the example scripts I've found online which plot percentage change rely on a fixed size of look-back buffer, or a size which is configurable via an input field.  So none of those achieve what I want either.

Am I missing something or is it simply impossible to do what I want in Pine script?

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no way in Pine to determine which `bar_index` is the left-most bar in the visible range. I'm afraid you'll have to resort to using a fixed lookback period.

Answer (score 1):

```
chart.left_visible_bar_time
```

and

```
chart.right_visible_bar_time
```

were released in June. Could be of interest if still relevant.

Source:
[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_chart{dot}left_visible_bar_time](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_chart%7Bdot%7Dleft_visible_bar_time)